# how to overlay a play button png over a thumbnail image that links to a shadowbox vimeo video

Tags: html, css, overlay, shadowbox

how to overlay a play button png over a thumbnail image that links to a shadowbox vimeo video

The shadow box works, thats not the issue. The issue implementing the transparent Play button over the thumbnail

html:

```
enter code here
<div class="postsingle">

        <a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/55138154" rel="Shadowbox" title="demo">
            <img class="demothumbnail" src="https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com/ts/410/203/410203139_640.jpg" alt="thumbnail image"> 
            <span class="playIcon"><img src="images\PlayButton.png">  </span>
        </a>

    </div>
```

css:
    .postsingle {
    margin:10px 4px 0 12px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    }

```
.demothumbnail{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px; height: auto;
    z-index: 1;

}

.demothumbnail span.playIcon{
    float: auto;
    position:absolute;
     z-index: 0;
}
```

please help

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I have a solution that may work... I just accomplished this for a youtube video thumbnail using shadowbox.

Answer (score 1):

Why the `float: auto` declaration?

The `.playIcon` span is NOT nested in `.demothumbnail`, that's why your CSS rule is not applying.

If you want the play icon overlay to stretch across the entire thumbnail, use:

```
.postSingle a {
    position: relative; /* The parent has to be set to relative */
}
.playIcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

If you mean you want to select the direct sibling of `.demothumbnail`, then use: `.demothumbnail + .playIcon`. See more details on sibling and child selectors [here](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

p/s: Please use a Fiddle to illustrate your issue in the future.